# Why isn't my program noticing the equivalency between letters?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am working on making a simple game of Hangman in Python 2. The code I have so far is the ground work I have for it, but it doesn't seem to be working. If I could have a simple wake-up call as to what about what code I made isn't working I would appreciate it.

Code:

```
secret_word = 'tracy'
secret_word_list = []
for letter in secret_word:
    secret_word_list += letter
print secret_word_list
def get_guess(guess = input("Guess: ")):
    while len(guess) != 1:
        print "Your guess must be exactly one character!"
        guess = input("Guess: ")
    while guess.isalpha() == False:
        print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
        guess = input("Guess: ")
    while guess.islower == False:
        print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
        guess = input("Guess: ")
    else:
        return guess

while True:
    if str(get_guess) in secret_word_list:
        print "That letter is in the secret word!"
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the secret word!"
        get_guess(guess = input("Guess: "))
```

Output:

[Output of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyi2c.png)

Comment: You don't need `secret_word_list`. You can simply use `secret_word` itself for your "in" check, like `if 't' in secret_word:`

Answer (score 1):

You've got several problems here, but the big one is that you're not calling functions, so you compare the function itself to the secret.

Code with fixes:

```
secret_word = 'tracy'  # Don't make secret_word_list, there's no point; just use the str itself since you only test len 1 strings against it anyway
print secret_word
def get_guess(guess):  # Don't make the default call input, that'll prompt once for an input and store it as the permanent default
    while True:
        # Test each condition and break loop only if all past; original code would never
        # recheck length if new value entered after testing isalpha
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "Your guess must be exactly one character!"
        elif not guess.islower():  # Add missing call parens on islower; use not, never compare to False; islower implicitly verifies isalpha, so avoid testing isalpha
            print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
        else:
            break  # Passed all tests, break loop
        # Get new guess if any test failed
        guess = raw_input("Guess: ")  # Use raw_input on Python 2, never input (which eval's the result of raw_input)
    # Removed else (loop always ends by breaking, using else nonsensical but harmless in original code too
    return guess

while True:
    # Move guess getting to if, because having it in else case never actually checked it
    if get_guess(raw_input("Guess: ")) in secret_word:
        print "That letter is in the secret word!"
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the secret word!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRNb9swDL37V7DpwQkQDGiPLXoYMKynAcXQHXYqGJmOtcqSIcrx/OszUnLTLOjmQxJH/Hjv8VHDnLrgb49HJhMpvUwhNvAAdYpo5hrgGr4EXyfo8ZXgLObFWU5bSB1Fqhl8gCFYn@7h18gJRiY9Ak4RbGJyLbD1hmAOIwTvZkgkYY483GiQ9XsG3KP18q9NgH6ecK4GOUjnXauGWtjLy34k5nX@3NxdoNTGEoejS2DQObB@GDNWTLW8DjH0QxIYgqcNUZqVCPnRCJgQKUPgXGig2KMngbGUrECeqbOO4DmOdJff9bmGZ@VEaDowwTc22eBzzV0kfAUXwlC42xYU1oAseoVo99ajk5yGYAqja8DTgeJZ4UimI/Oqeu1Tp/meJjigGwkEmoygAWzlO8sqYoJldEOHpxqSIsmLYHD1ADfvwPUpSq9@hjFCDoJe57iT@r/RJAEdPIHpUGwhfa5Wp2xyCiekkvbJsgsTxXWZyuemgd4yKyRTOEfyLMVgCbzPXpH8bWEtMvQaBCnAV3RM92@RYPvBWWMVjATa1hK/8dwCB8BDsM0/Ffg/S4Tcw6CAcZQuKTL9LVeZqBB8QmYVX6hpY96eDftsgI@U8shKU52/X1agRXFScwotAQ8QcXrJplyvHvWvO1httNAPwXc6Uxmf8v7C7Zt85WAtBhUbklikLj6OxLoPoX1P31QF3Hfqw0FIKE1YZ5uik/Vj8VbDsJsLJxF1K8NSbXOkD55lllbmCjvpKd7oXabnL0ydQsitZIvH6AvHqrrcoWv4JjAWBWTH8xTFBbYVUcmg@qTDQ55t0iYZRZ5YoS7OHGUQM@RlEUK2LKs9vzI@Enaj1c5umfdZL4Z5lptjsYX4SqPz5ZYzQDMWs/xtlI@TdVU@KnA8IlZ1hdWuMlVT0R8)

Note: I kept the kinda odd behavior of having `get_guess` take an argument, but then reprompt for guesses on failure. A saner solution would be to remove the `guess` argument entirely, and move the `guess = raw_input("Guess: ")` to the top of the `while` loop (removing the `else` block at the end).

Comment: this is was extremely helpful! thank you so much for taking the time to walk me through this, i’m fairly new so i don’t know the niches (such as the never comparing to false, as well as the raw_input), but i clearly need to update myself on some of the more basic principles too. the reason the function takes a parameter is because it is required by the assignment to take a parameter, which i thought was inefficient but couldn’t really do anything about it. again, thank you for the amazing answer.

Comment: @robs: Well, if you're fairly new, may I suggest learning Python 3 instead? Python 2 stopped getting new features years ago, and will stop being supported entirely at the end of this year. Among other things, it made `input` equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input`, so your choice of APIs would have been correct on Python 3. :-)

Comment: i would love to switch, however the current course i'm taking requires this to be done in python 2. no idea why. this is the final assignment for the exam, so i'm hoping i can get this done and move on to python 3. thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

`get_guess` is a function, you need to put `()` after it to call the function.

You shouldn't put the call to `input()` as a default argument. The default value is evaluated once, when the function is defined, not every time the function is called. You should assign `guess` inside the function.

You should test for all the invalid inputs in a single loop.

```
def get_guess():
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess:")
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "Your guess must be exactly one character!"
            continue
        if not guess.isalpha() or not guess.islower():
            print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
            continue
        break
    return guess

while True:
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess in secret_word_list:
        print "That letter is in the secret word!"
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the secret word!"
```

Comment: Your fixed code ended up surprisingly similar to mine. :-) Minor correction: `!` is not an operator in Python; you need to spell out `not`. Also, `str.islower` implicitly requires at least one cased character, and since the known length is 1, the test for `isalpha` isn't necessary at all.